# html rotate entire canvas by 90 degrees

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have an image drawn to an html cavas. I would like to be able to rotate the image by 90 degrees but I can't seem to find an example on how to rotate the entire canvas image, only an object on the canvas.

Does anyone have example code to rotate an entire canvas by 90 degrees?

I accepted an anwser below but wanted to provide additional example code : http://jsfiddle.net/VTyNF/1/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2) 
  context.rotate(90 * (Math.PI / 180));   
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(188 - canvas.width/2, 50 - canvas.height/2, 200, 100);
  context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 7;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide some example code please?

Comment: i guess like this? http://jsfiddle.net/VTyNF/1/ After it rotates it should be vertical instead of horizontal, and still in the center of the canvas.

Comment: Keep in mind you can't rotate any drawings that already exist on your canvas. So first clear every existing drawing off the canvas with context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); Then, to rotate your entire canvas, you do context.rotate(90*Math.PI/180); Then redraw everything you want on the canvas and those new drawings will be rotated 90 degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to apply this rotation before you draw your canvas. You can't rotate anything that is already drawn.

So:

To rotate a canvas, the `content.rotate()` expects a value in radians.  So first, lets make it simple by converting degrees to radians using:

```
function getRadianAngle(degreeValue) {
    return degreeValue * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

You may want to translate the canvas first before rotating so that it's origin is set correctly.

`context.translate(context.width/2,context.height/2);`

Once we know what value we want, we simply rotate the canvas before we draw anything!

Please note, in your example, the rectangle you have drawn, is also being offset in the first two parameters of `context.rect(`X,Y,W,H)`.

I find it's easier to set widths as variables, then do simple math to re position the box automatically, notice now it sits perfectly in the center, and rotates nicely!

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/VTyNF/6/

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the help so far. This seems to rotate it from the top left. Is there a way to have the rotation from the center?

Comment: Do context.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2) just before rotating.

Comment: Hey @user1308743, I have edited my fiddle for you. Added a translate property!

Comment: @user1308743 I have fixed the fiddle and made it much cleaner, happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Say your [`canvas`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/the-canvas-element.html) element has [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) "foo". In JavaScript you could do something like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('foo'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Rotates the canvas 90 degrees
context.rotate(90 * (Math.PI / 180));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use CSS to rotate the `<canvas>` element with `transform: rotate(90deg);`?

Comment: why would he want that

Comment: I want the actual image to be rotated, not just look rotated by rotating the canvas element. The image will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily rotate the image ninety degrees by manipulating the pixel data.  If your canvas isn't square, you will have to make some choices about what the 'correct' answer will be.

Use the `getImageData` function to retrieve the pixels, manipulate them in the usual manner, and use `putImageData` to display the result.

Answer (score 0):

This version doesn't require center point for 90 degree turn:
(Not as easy for newcomers becase it's a 1d array with 4 values per pixel.

```
    //...
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d', {willReadFrequently: true});
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    const file = inp.files[0]; // file from user input
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    img.addEventListener('load', function () {
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        rotateClockwiseBy90(canvas, context, img);
    }   
}

function rotateClockwiseBy90(canvas, context, img) {
    const width = canvas.width;
    const height = canvas.height;

    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    const rotatedImageData = context.createImageData(height, width);

    //[redIndex, greenIndex, blueIndex, alphaIndex]
    const width4 = width * 4;
    const height4 = height * 4;

    for (let y = 0; y < height4; y += 4) {
        for (let x = 0; x < width4; x += 4) {
            rotatedImageData.data[x * height + (height4 - y - 1) - 3] = imageData.data[y * width + x];
            rotatedImageData.data[x * height + (height4 - y - 1) - 2] = imageData.data[y * width + x + 1];
            rotatedImageData.data[x * height + (height4 - y - 1) - 1] = imageData.data[y * width + x + 2];
            rotatedImageData.data[x * height + (height4 - y - 1)] = imageData.data[y * width + x + 3];
        }
    }

    const cw = canvas.width;
    canvas.width = canvas.height;
    canvas.height = cw;
    context.putImageData(rotatedImageData, 0, 0);
}
```

If someone is trying to understand the logic:

```
rotatedImageData.data[x * height ...
```

should really be:

```
rotatedImageData.data[x / 4 * height * 4 ...
```

because for the rotated array `x` represents row number and height represents row length, but the result is same.

Version for counterclockwise rotation:

```
for (let y = 0; y < height4; y += 4) {
    for (let x = 0; x < width4; x += 4) {
        rotatedImageData.data[(height4 * (width - x/4) - height4 + y)] = imageData.data[y * width + x];
        rotatedImageData.data[(height4 * (width - x/4) - height4 + y) + 1] = imageData.data[y * width + x + 1];
        rotatedImageData.data[(height4 * (width - x/4) - height4 + y) + 2] = imageData.data[y * width + x + 2];
        rotatedImageData.data[(height4 * (width - x/4) - height4 + y) + 3] = imageData.data[y * width + x + 3];
    }
}
```